# Event Subscriber not called in Console Command

Tags: symfony, elastica

I have to run a command on a cron to update the database. However, this seems to create problems with the Elastica index I have. Presumably because the event subscriber isn't being called by a command.

My service looks like this

```
fos_elastica.listener.application.client:
        class: 'Alpha\RMSBundle\EventListener\ClientListener'
        arguments:
            - '@fos_elastica.object_persister.application.client'
            - 'Alpha\RMSBundle\Entity\Position'
            - ['postPersist', 'postUpdate', 'postRemove', 'preRemove']
            - id
        calls:
            - [ setContainer, [ '@service_container' ] ]
        tags:
            - { name: 'doctrine.event_subscriber' }
```

Is there a way to make sure the event subscriber is called?

Comment: If this strictly for testing, you can always add an instruction in the code you're trying to execute to test if it was run... The writing of a foobar file at the root of your symfony app for example.